# jython throwing nameerror for no apparent reason

Tags: python, jira, jython

I am trying to use jython code from JIRA post function

I have create a file called foo,py and placed into jython Lib directory

foo.py looks like

```
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from smtplib import SMTPException
from smtplib import SMTP


class my_mail(object):

        def spam(subj, to, body):

                msg = MIMEText(body, 'html')
                msg['Subject'] = subj
                msg['To'] = to
                msg['Importance'] = 'high'
                sender = 'abd@abd.com'
                passwd = 'password'
                s = SMTP('smtp.office365.com', 587)
                s.ehlo()
                s.starttls()
                s.ehlo()
                s.login(sender, passwd)
                s.sendmail(sender, [to], msg.as_string())
                s.quit()
```

The calling program looks like

```
to = 'abcd@bad.com'
sub = " test "
body " some body"
import foo

nmail = foo.my_mail()
nmail.spam(subj, to, body)
```

With this, I always get error

root cause:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "<string>", line 35, in <module> File "/usr2/atlassian/application-data/jira/jss/jython_2.5.2/Lib/foo.py", line 18, in spam s.starttls() NameError: global name 'server' is not defined
```

No matter what I do, it is always line 18 in foo.py :-(

This foo.py works fine, if I use command line python with same function call.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It's not your problem, but why have you put your script into the Lib directory? That's for installed packages.

Comment: It seems likely that Python is picking up the wrong `foo.py`, especially if it works from the command line.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I need to call the same code from multiple places in JIRA, hence added that to Lib If not lib, what is the better place to add my own library?